# Framework with ID x does not exist on slave with ID y

Tags: configuration, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I keep getting this error on my marathon dashboard

```
Framework with ID 'a5a96e8c-c3f2-4591-8eb3-43f8dc902585-0001' does not exist on slave with ID '9959ba51-f6f7-448f-99d2-289767f12179-S2'.
```

The path to make this error occur is to click "Sandbox" next to a task on the main marathon dashboard.

The path looks something like this

```
http://mesos.dev.internal/#/slaves/9959ba51-f6f7-448f-99d2-289767f12179-S2/frameworks/a5a96e8c-c3f2-4591-8eb3-43f8dc902585-0001/executors/rabbitmq.6316bf0a-d089-11e5-b895-fa163e196ca3/browse
```

However, if I go to the slave through the slave panel, and click the framework from there, I am able to access the sandbox. The link in this case looks like the following

```
http://mesos.dev.internal/#/slaves/9959ba51-f6f7-448f-99d2-289767f12179-S2/browse?path=%2Ftmp%2Fmesos%2Fslaves%2Fc223b6b1-cef8-4599-8cea-b402bf20afc5-S0%2Fframeworks%2F20160108-205802-16842879-5050-1210-0001%2Fexecutors%2Frabbitmq.91b8bbf6-ceba-11e5-8047-0242ffdabb3e%2Fruns%2Fc66eb4d5-ea6d-451d-982f-6a0d29b25441
```

Any ideas on what I have misconfigured?

Comment: Can you check whether you are using same mesos version in all slaves and masters?

Answer (score 1):

Mesos Web UI does not proxy logs through `mesos-master` (although it would  be nice). Basically you need to be able to resolve slave's name from your browser (computer) and port `5051` needs to be open for you:

```
$ nc -z -w5 mesos.dev.internal 5051; echo $?
0 # port is open
```

It's not a good idea to leave Mesos ports open for public, so either you can:

- connect via VPN
- whitelist your public IP on all slaves
- use CLI instead of Web UI

Using CLI is quite easy, once you set master's URI. You can install it:

```
pip install mesos.cli mesos.interface
```

Then you can list all tasks using `mesos ps`, or fetch `stdout`:

```
  mesos tail -f rabbitmq.6316bf0a-d089-11e5-b895-fa163e196ca3
```

and `stderr`:

```
  mesos tail -f rabbitmq.6316bf0a-d089-11e5-b895-fa163e196ca3 stderr
```

Note that the mesos-cli is no longer developed, similar features and much more you should be able to do with Mesosphere's [DCOS CLI](https://docs.mesosphere.com/administration/introcli/cli/)